# Keep getting Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I keep getting a Syntax error for some reason. The code looks good to me.. Am I doing something wrong?

```
 query = "UPDATE misperDB SET name=?, surname=?, DOB=?, " &
    "[NHS No]=?, [Hosp No]=?, [Info Source]=?, [Missing From]=?, [Reporter Name]=?, [Reporter Contact]=?, Ethnicity=?, [Hair Colour=?], [Eye Colour=?], [Top Clothing=?], [Bottom Clothing=?], Cannula=?, [OBS Time=?], [OBS Date=?], [High Risk=?], Notes=?" &
    " WHERE id=?"
```

Comment: For what database? SQL Server? It shouldn't be a great mystery, the errors are usually very specific.

Comment: From here  _[Hair Colour=?],_ everything is wrong. It's  _[Hair Colour]=?,_

Comment: also the column naming is horrible

Comment: You really should use named parameters, because with just one thing off, it is heard to tell where it is wrong.  What if your notes field has a comma in it????

Comment: you can also use XML literals so that the SQL can easily span lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Steve commented, the brackets are used incorrectly for some variables:

```
 query = "UPDATE misperDB SET name=?, surname=?, DOB=?, " &
    "[NHS No]=?, [Hosp No]=?, [Info Source]=?, [Missing From]=?, [Reporter Name]=?, [Reporter Contact]=?, Ethnicity=?, 
--[Hair Colour=?], 
[Hair Colour]=?, [Eye Colour]=?, [Top Clothing]=?, [Bottom Clothing]=?, Cannula=?, [OBS Time]=?, [OBS Date]=?, [High Risk]=?, Notes=?" &
    " WHERE id=?"
```